# Perl Programming

Tags: perl

I have these questions. But I don't know how to prove it or if I'm right. Are my answers right?

Find all complete lines of a file which contain only a row of any number of the letter x

- x*
- ^x+$
- ^x*$  <-This one
- ^xxxxx$

Find all complete lines of a file which contain a row consisting only the letter x but ignoring any leading or trailing space on the line.

- ^\s* x+\s*$ <--This one
- ^\s(x*)\s$
- \s* x+\s*
- ^\s+x+\s+$

I tried to use this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'data.txt';

open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename ) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
    chomp $row;
    print "$row\n";
}
```

I tried this code but I got error at `(^`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'data.txt';

open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename ) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {

    if ( ^x*$ ) {
        print "This is";
    }
}
```

Comment: how about write some tests?

Comment: I tried to use thisuse strict;
use warnings;
 
my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
 
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  print "$row\n";
}

Comment: I tried this code but I got error at (^

use strict;
use warnings;
 
my $filename = 'data.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
 
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
        if (^x*$){
                print "This is";
        }
}

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're talking about regular expressions and how to use them in Perl. Your question seems to be whether the answers you picked to homework are correct.

The code you've added should do what you want, but it has syntax errors.

```
if ( ^x*$ ) {
    print "This is";
}
```

Your *pattern* is correct, but you don't know how to use a regular expression in Perl. You're missing the actual operator to tell Perl that you want a regular expression.

The short form is this, where I've highlighted the important part with `#`

```
if ( /^x*$/ ) {
     #    #
```

The slashes `//` tell Perl that it should match a pattern. The long form of it is:

```
if ( $_ =~ m/^x*$/ ) {
     ## ## ##    #
```

`$_` is the variable that you are matching against a pattern. The `=~` is the *matching operator*. The `m//` constructs a pattern to match with. If you use `//` you can leave out the `m`, but it's clearer to put it in.

The `$_` is called *topic*. It's like a default variable that stuff goes into in Perl if you don't specify another variable.

```
while ( <$fh> ) {
    print $_ if $_ =~ m/foo/; # print all lines that contain foo
}
```

This code can be written as `$_`, because a lot of commands in Perl assume that you mean `$_` when you don't explicitly name a variable.

```
while ( <$fh> ) {    # puts each line in $_
    print if m/foo/; # prints $_ if $_ contains foo
}
```

You code looks like you wanted to do that, but in fact you have a `$row` in your loop. That's good, because it is more explicit. That means it's easier to read. So what you need to do for your match is:

```
while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $row =~ m/^x*$/ ) {
        print "This is";
    }
}
```

Now you will *iterate* each line of the file behind the `$fh` filehandle, and check if it matches the pattern `^x*$`. If it does, you print _"This is". That doesn't sound very useful.

Consider this example, where I am using the `__DATA__` section instead of a file.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $row =~ m/^x*$/ ) {
        print "This is";
    }
}

__DATA__
foo
xxx

x
xxxxx
bar
```

This will print:

```
This isThis isThis isThis is
```

It really does not seem to be very useful. It would make more sense to include the line that matched.

```
if ( $row =~ m/^x*$/ ) {
    print "match: $row";
}
```

Now we get this:

```
match: xxx
match: 
match: x
match: xxxxx
```

That's almost what we expected. It matches a single `x`, and a bunch of `x`s. It did not match `foo` or `bar`. But it does match an empty line.

That's because you picked the wrong pattern.

The `*` multiplier means  *match as many as possible, as least **none***.
The `+` multiplier means *match as many as possible, at least **one***.

So your pattern should be the one with `+`, or it will match if there is nothing, because *start of the line*, no `x`, *end of the line* matches an empty line.

While you're at it, you could also rename your variable. Unless you're dealing with CSV, which has rows of data, you have *lines*, not *rows*. So `$line` would be a better name for your variable. Giving variables good, descriptive names is very important because it makes it easier to understand your program.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = 'data.txt';

open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename ) 
    or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/^x+$/ ) {
        print "match: $line";
    }
}
```